# Combining Scatter Chart with Box Plot in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, boxplot

I am creating a Box Plot(also known as box and whisker plot)through SSRS and I came across a question by Pavan Keerthi. Somehow his example gave me a vision of how I wanted my report to be. What I wanted to do is to create a line similar to the ones on his example below wherein there is a line passing through the mean of his box plot chart.

[image]

[image]

As per my observation he made use of a scatter chart to create the line which he combined with the box plot chart. Upon trying mine didn't show any line but a single dot instead. I was wondering if I was missing something. Here is my example:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon further research I have found that the line I needed to add on my chart is called the **threshold** **line**. It is created by adding a Strip line by accessing the chart properties.

[image]

Set the interval Offset where you want to place the threshold line. Take note that you may set the value dynamically by using Expression. After that you may customize the threshold line's appearance by altering the border color and style.

[image]